# Why is the gradetable wrong when creating multiple named exams?

Tags: exam, gradetable, textmerg

I have many students in my class and would like to provide each of them with a named exam. However with the following approach the gradetable, total number of questions and total number of points are wrong, see attached screenshot.[image]

I am using the "exam" class.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{students.lst}
  Sam Student
  John Doe
  Bat Man
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{textmerg,titling,enumitem,kantlipsum}
\newlist{examqns}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examqns]{label=Question \arabic*, font=\bfseries, wide, ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}
  \title{Exam --- Fall 2022}
  \date{Date of Examination}

  \Fields{\studentname}
  \Merge{students.lst}{%
    \clearpage% use \cleardoublepage if printing double-sided
    \author{\bf{\studentname}}
    \maketitle

%---

The exam has \numpages\ page and \numquestions\ questions that result in \numpoints\ points. \\

%\noindent


\begin{center}
\addpoints
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}

%content---
\begin{questions}

\question[10]
Why is there air?

\question
What if there were no air?
\begin{parts}
\part[5]
Describe the effect on the balloon industry.
\part[5]
Describe the effect on the aircraft industry.
\end{parts}

\question[10] If the universe were to end, how would you know?
\begin{parts}
    \part Define the universe.  Give three examples.
    \part Compute x2 dx.
\end{parts}

\end{questions}



%---
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: The short answer is that exam class was designed for one exam per run, not three exams.  I would create a PDF with a blank name and run textmerge together with pdfpages and overlap the original name using a tikzpicture.

Answer (score 2):

It was slightly more complicated than my comment, but the gist was there.  The tricky part is locating where the name is supposed to go.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\Fields{\studentname}
  \Merge{students.lst}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[page=1]{test6}};% original PDF
      \path (current page text area.north) ++(0,-1.7cm) node{\textbf{\huge\studentname}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \newpage
    %\includepdf[pages={2-}]{test6}
  }
\end{document}
```

---

This version puts the name on **every** page.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{\put ({\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin},-6.5cm)
  {\makebox[\textwidth]{\textbf{\huge\studentname}}}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\Fields{\studentname}
  \Merge{students.lst}{%
    \includepdf{test6}
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for this approach. However, I'm wondering how to alter your code if my original PDF has n pages. I would like to print the student's name on each of the n pages in the same spot without specifying how many pages my original pdf has.

Comment: Did you notice the commented out call to \includepdf?

Comment: Yes I did notice your comment but unfortunately it does not print anything onto the proceeding pages